# How to make an image remain in its same size

Tags: html, css, image

I put an image in the center over a fixed background image and I would like the image to stay the exact same size (not grow smaller nor bigger) when rendering the page smaller or bigger in any way (left to right and top to bottom).
I tried min-width and max-width, which made the image stay the same size when rendering the page from left or right, but the image does grow smaller or bigger when rendering the page from up or bottom.

Any help will be welcomed

```css
    body {
    background-image: url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    .still{
    padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<img
   src= "http://www.comptonacres.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/compton-acres-poole-dorset-the-japanese-garden-02-1024x576.jpg" class= "still"
   style="width:90%"
>
```

Comment: maybe you could also added min-height ?

Comment: Don't set the width using percentages

Comment: remove cover .. and keep the default size

Comment: It doesn't change anything, and the cover is for the background-image

Comment: DId you try removing the width on the image, it's currently set as 90% `style="width:90%"`

Comment: Yes I set the width to 90vh. And ironically, the % allowed the image's size to remain when rendering up to bottom, but not left to right. It's reverse for vh, the image's size remains when rendering left to right, but not up to bottom.

Comment: @Louisff9 that is still not a fixed number

Comment: What is the final goal here? Have the image centered vertically and horizontally and not change size no matter what the browser size is?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: and what happens when the browser size is smaller than the image?

Comment: The same result as you can see in this website for an example: http://kyokainorinne.wikia.com/wiki/Ky%C5%8Dkai_no_Rinne_Wiki (look at the set of images of Anime, Manga, Characters).
You'd be forced to render the browser bigger to see the whole image.

Comment: Set the image to a fixed width or don't set any width and it won't resize

Comment: How do I set to a fixed width? What is the code for that?

Comment: @Louisff9 your current code sets the image width to 90%, change the 90% to something like 300px for example

Comment: Ah, so % and vh are the cause. With px however, the image remains still.

Comment: @Louisff9 i mentioned this in the second comment, the image remains still is what you wanted

Comment: Thank you. I never knew the problems with units.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the inline styles and access css give it a fixed width:

```
.still {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Otherwise in html change `style="width: 90%"` to `style="display: block; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;"`

Comment: It doesn't work. And it makes the image not be centered anymore.

Comment: it's going to get overridden by the inline css on the image tag

Comment: then set the inline style to your fixed width... text-align: center or margin: 0 auto

Comment: Add it to your answer because your current answer do not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img width="300">` it is one of default img
tag properties and don't use percentages if you wanna fixed sizes

Comment: You mean <img width= "300px">?

Comment: @Louisff9 no, units are needed when you set inline style like in your original code